# How can I unlock rotation and displacement for multiple objects at once?

Tags: transforms, archimesh-add-on

I have created a collection of objects that includes archimesh objects.

I want to duplicate, move and rotate the collection.

Since archimesh objects have some of its properties locked, I have to unlock every property of every one of them.

I tried locking and unlocking all the properties of the selection set, but did not work. Only selecting one sub object at a time worked.

Is there a way to select all objects in the collection and have all objects properties unlocked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Blender if you want to change the same property on multiple objects you have to press (and keep pressed) the <kbd>ALT</kbd> modifier key beforehand, otherwise only the active object (Yellow outline) will update.

[image]

Comment: What the actual heck. Since when has this been a thing!?!

Comment: @WillChen Sshh... Do like everybody else and pretend it went out in the last patch and you didn't lose part of your sanity because you thought that was not possible ;)

Comment: Very useful feature Gorgious. Thanks for sharing. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm still learning BPY myself, but here is a script I whipped up to **assign off** a stated collection's object's transform locks (location, rotation, scale). Run the script vie the text-editor. Enjoy.

## Assigning individual transform-locks

```
import bpy

COLLECTION_NAME = "Collection 1"

for collection in bpy.data.collections:
   if collection.name == COLLECTION_NAME:
       for obj in collection.all_objects:
            obj.lock_location[0] = False
            obj.lock_location[1] = False
            obj.lock_location[2] = False
            obj.lock_rotation[0] = False
            obj.lock_rotation[1] = False
            obj.lock_rotation[2] = False
            obj.lock_scale[0] = False
            obj.lock_scale[1] = False
            obj.lock_scale[2] = False
```

## Assigning group transform-locks

````
import bpy

COLLECTION_NAME = "Collection 1"

for collection in bpy.data.collections:
   if collection.name == COLLECTION_NAME:
       for obj in collection.all_objects:
           for i in range(len(obj.lock_location)):
               obj.lock_location[i] = False
           for i in range(len(obj.lock_rotation)):
               obj.lock_rotation[i] = False
           for i in range(len(obj.lock_scale)):
               obj.lock_scale[i] = False
```
````